# Look up element in dictionary and check type of object

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I check if `'ksize'` in `config = {'median': {}, 'gauss': {'ksize' :( 3,3), 'sigmaX': 3}}` is a tuple? Is there any option to get values only from `'ksize'` and not from all the `gauss` values? I am looking for a universal function if I need to check different values in different config values in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
if type(config["gauss"]["ksize"]) is tuple:
  print("It is a tuple")
```

use the `type` built in function in python.

`print(config["gauss"]["ksize"])`prints the tuple(3,3)

Comment: `isinstance()` is python's preferred method to test whether an object is of a specific type

Comment: ah I see. Thx for letting me too cause I thought we had to use that `type`. `isIntance()` seems to be more initutive and easy

Comment: the advantage of `isinstance` is that it respects inheritance of classes. often just the behavior of an object counts, so the tested object is allowed to be of a subclass. if I needed to know specifically if an object is of a class and not of a subclass, I would use `type(obj)` too.

Answer (score 1):

```
config = {'median': {}, 'gauss': {'ksize' :( 3,3), 'sigmaX': 3}}
print(isinstance(config["gauss"]["ksize"],tuple))
```

Output

> True